# Wordpress - What is the best way to disable the TAG pages of a blog?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I dont want the TAG pages to show in my Wordpress, and I want a redirect to the homepage not a noindex.

I cannot use NGINX redirects as my Wordpress in multilingual the word "tag" is translatable it can be changed (and I do not really want to leave it to chance, that in a year when we will add another language I will forget to add this redirect)

Currently I am using this:

```
public function my_template_include($original_template)
{
    global $wp_query;

// we dont use tags...
    if(is_tag()){
        wp_redirect('/',301);
        exit();
    }
}

add_filter('template_include', array($this, 'my_template_include'), 10, 1);
```

But I am pretty sure that there should be a better way then this.

P.S. I have used: unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type
But, it removed the option to ADD tags but will not remove the current existing tags in the system and will not remove the pages it created!

Comment: Can you please provide more information about how you are displaying the tags. Pretty sure you can remove the link from "the_tags" or you can create a custom query to show the tags without the a href tag.

Comment: @YuxelYuseinov - that's irrelevant.  In WP there's a way to remove the archive(s) for given taxonomies.  "How it's displayed" is not part of the equation - OP is almost certainly using the built-in taxonomy, which has built-in systems for showing tags, categories, etc.

Comment: @cale-b you have a point :))

Comment: @YuxelYuseinov  yes its a built in taxonomy, and my problem is to remove the page that this tag created the /tag/some_tag/

Comment: @cale_b yes you are correct, this is the default post taxonomy.

Comment: Hey @AlexFrenkel - If cale_b's answer helped you, the courteous thing to do would be to select his answer as the correct one **and** up-vote it to give him reputation points for his effort.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you want to use the built-in WP filter `register_taxonomy_args` which allows you to filter / adjust *all* taxonomies, including the built-in "tag" taxonomy.  You would use the filter to disable the `public` setting, which should remove it from the front-end of WP. (If `public` doesn't do what you want specifically, then read up on the [register_taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) args, and adjust / test as necessary).

```
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'my_tags_disable', 10, 3 );

function my_tags_disable( $args, $name, $object_type ) {
    // if it's no the "tag" taxonomy, don't make changes
    if ( 'post_tag' !== $name ) {
        return $args;
    }

    // override the specific arguments to remove the archive from the front-end
    $args['public'] = FALSE;
    $args['publicly_queryable'] = FALSE;

    // return the modified arguments
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Did this answer help at all? Have you tried it / had any luck?

Comment: How would I modify this to remove tag pages only for tags that have less than 7 posts related to them?

Comment: @SeanLang  - that's worthy of a new question, it's not a simple change here.  If you ask the questions, you can come back and comment to me here with a link to the new question and I could take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540983/wordpress-what-is-the-best-way-to-disable-hide-tag-pages-when-there-are-less-t